# Can I suppress the visual/audible bell in Mail when I press ⌥ (option) plus a symbol?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, audio, bettertouchtool

I've configured [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) to allow me to toggle read/unread status of an email when I press ⌥/ (option slash, a convenient shortcut near the arrow keys), using the "Trigger menu bar menu item" action.  (See below screenshot.)

[image]

The shortcut works—when I trigger it, the read/unread status changes.  (BTT is smooth as glass, I **LOVE** it.)

However, Mail.app **also** makes an audible and visual bell (screen flash and a sound) when I trigger the shortcut.  It does this whether or not BTT is running or configured.

Is there some way I can suppress this bell sound and flash for this particular keyboard shortcut for Mail?

(I'm running Mail 9.3 on macOS 10.11.6, and BetterTouchTool 1.912 (523).)

---

P.S.: I tried several other unbound keyboard shortcuts, without configuring them in BTT but just pressing them in Mail, and all made the same flash and sound.  I have no reason to think they will *not* make the same annoying sound if configured to actually do something through BTT.

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned off **Sound Effects**
*System Preferences>Sound*
Untick the box *play user interface sounds* effects [image]

Comment: I don't want to suppress *all* user interface sound effects.  They are quite handy when they're appropriate.  But when I am using a command I intend to use, I don't want extra noise.  Thank you, though.